# Set-Cookie present in header response but missing in browser

Tags: php, session, cookies

Basically Session is not working. Session is getting generated and getting stored in the proper folder of the server, but not getting stored in the browser as the usual `PHPSESSID cookie`. The `phpinfo()` shows that the Set-Cookie headers are being sent, but Set-Cookie headers are missing in the response that the browser gets. Please check the below screenshots:

Set-Cookie headers present from the server side:

[image: phpinfo screenshot showing Set-Cookie header]

Set-Cookie headers missing in the response the browser gets:

[image: browser screenshot showing no Set-Cookie in response]

Another info is, if I use javascript to set cookie then it works and shows up in the browser's developer tool.

Everything regarding session is ok, just that the cookie it tries to set on the browser seems to be not setting.

Comment: have you made sure that you are sending nothing before this? try moving the `session_start()` to the first line of code.

Comment: @bansi yes it's on the top.. but anyway, it's related to cookies..even setcookie() function is not setting any cookie in the browser even if the response is present in the phpinfo() output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering the cause and fix as it may help someone in future and save many hours:

This error happened in a site previously built by someone else. This error seemed quite unusual and I thought the problem is most probably with Apache. I removed Apache and reinstalled to no effect. Then I installed Nginx to see if the problem is with the Web Server software or the Server itself. And I found that Session is working fine in Nginx. So the problem was definitely with Apache somewhere.

As I checked the files found that **in the .htaccess file somewhere down below Cookie was unset**!!

```
Header unset Cookie
Header unset Set-Cookie
```

Never thought someone would have put that! But anyway, removing the above fixed the problem.

Comment: well spotted - must have been 'interesting' (read 'frustrating') trying to work out what was happening. ;-/

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same behavior with a service provider of mine. Turned out to be a caching problem on their side (varnish cache).

Luckily I was able to **disable Varnish-Cache** via the provided admin-backend. After that, the Set-Cookie headers were present in the client response.